# How to customize CSS of input element in iView?

Tags: css, vue.js, iview-ui

I use Vue's single file components and wanted to try iView UI framework. Consider there is following piece of code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <i-input class="cred"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then I want to change the width of my input. Just for example, to check that changes take effect:

```
<style scoped>
input {
  width: 10px;
}
</style>
```

But it has no effect. Tried `i-input` too.

```
<style scoped>
.cred {
  width: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Works as expected.
Which CSS selector should I use?

Comment: Maybe `.ivu-input`. You can view element's class in [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: Yes it works, but it's still kind of weird for me why it has no effect for pure "input" selector

Comment: It is because of selectors [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Looks like `<i-input>` has width css-rule and it is more specific than your input css-rule. In developer tools you can also view all css-rules and which one is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Vue/iView allows you to use the inline `style` attribute and pass it a width, or you can change the `.ivu-input-wrapper` CSS class and give it the `with` you want.

```js
Vue.use(iview);
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/iview/dist/styles/iview.css");
#app {
  padding: 32px;
}

.ivu-input-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <i-input v-model="value" placeholder="CSS changed..."></i-input>
  <i-input v-model="value" placeholder="Inline style changed..." style="width: 200px"></i-input>
</div>
```